# How to determine if any instance was created from AMI in AWS Marketplace or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami, aws-marketplace

I have an AWS EC2 instance and I need to check if this specific instance was created by an AMI from AWS Marketplace or not. How to get such information?

I looked into the instance detail of the instance but there is no such information. AMI Name is not displayed too. It says that the AMI was deleted or private.

The reason I need to check this is because I am going to do a VM export on this instance but one of the prerequisites says that the instance must not be created by an AMI from AWS Marketplace.

Comment: In my experience you should be able to see which AMI ID was used to launch the instance. If your says that it's been deleted then it's probably been deleted so if you do tend to clean up your own AMIs then it's more likely this one was from your own AMIs you since deleted because I would expect marketplace AMIs to be less likely to disappear. At this stage I don't think you can actually tell for certain